# How connect NFC Module ITEAD PN532 to the new Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: nfc

I bought an NFC Shield Module, ITEAD, which has got a 26-pin port. The new Raspberry Pi 2 Model B has got 40 GPIO pins.

I connected a ribbon cable between the NFC module (red stripe on RST_OUT pin) and to the left (when reading the writings) to the Raspberry GPIO. But I'm not sure at all. I tried to use libnfc to communicate but I got an error :

```
ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_spi:/dev/spidev0.0:500000
ERROR: Unable to open NFC device: pn532_uart:/dev/ttyAMA0
```

I think the ribbon cable is not connected the way it's supposed to, because I've installed libraries and drivers without any problems. Do you know how to connect a ribbon cable with the new Raspberry Pi 2?

The old Pi had a 13-pin port like the ITEAD NFC Module that I bought. I tried use SPI and 12C to communicate.

[image: I connected rst_out of the vertical 13-pin port to...]

[image: .. to Pin 1 on the Pi]

I connected rst_out of the vertical 13-pins port (1st picture)
...to the Pin 1 on the raspberry (2nd picture)

Comment: There is info at http://blog.iteadstudio.com/to-drive-itead-pn532-nfc-module-with-raspberry-pi/  Have you set the jumpers?  I'd be tempted to try I2C.  It may be easier to check it is working.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you edited your question to add a photo of your connections.

Typically a red stripe indicates pin 1.  The red stripe should be over the pins at the top edge of the board, i.e. the pins furthest away from the edge with the USB sockets.

See http://elinux.org/RPi_Low-level_peripherals#Model_A.2B.2C_B.2B_and_B2

[image: pinout]

Comment: Could you confirm that the red stripe end is over Pin 1 of the Pi and the top of the 13x2 header at the top right of the ITEAD board?  If so that looks correct to me.

Comment: Yep I do confirm. That's a relief. i gonna reinstall and keep you informed. Thank you

Comment: I forgot to say that I try with SPI and I2C